# Apk file which made using eas build of react native expo cli is not works on real device

Tags: react-native, expo-eas

I've made an app using React Native Expo Cli. It works fine on Expo Go App and I've generated apk file using eas build --profile development --platform android and eas build --platform android. But these does not work on real device.
I've used eas build for making apk because earlier I was using expo build:android but now If I write this command on cmd and hit enter then after some seconds it is showing **"Unsupported SDK version: our app builders do not support SDK version 45, yet. The latest SDK version is 45.0.0. Unsupported SDK version"**. You can check my app.json and eas.json file.

**app.json**

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "RoyalVivahVendor",
    "slug": "RoyalVivahVendor",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      },
      "package": "com.royalvivah.royalvivahvendor",
      "versionCode": 1
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    }
  }
}
```

**eas.json**

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 0.52.0"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "production": {
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
     }
    }
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: Check the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72204856/how-to-build-expo-apk-using-eas-build. The solution has been provided already. Hope it helps.